# Nikkon DSLR messing up SD Cards

Tags: nikon, dslr, equipment-damage, sdcard, data-corruption

So here's my dilemma. I have a Nikon DSLR, unsure the model at the moment, that eats SD cards. Every time I use an SD card with this device it destroys the card, rendering all of the data on it unusable. When I look for physical damage the slot looks ok. No connectors sticking out or moved. But when I look at the SD card there are marks engraved into the connectors of the card.

Has anyone else experienced this issue? Has anyone resolved this issue? Are the engraved lines just regular wear and tear? Is there a formatting issue that could cause this issue?

Comment: i am having same problem,
So many card have been destroyed using my Nikon D3200! Why

Comment: what brand/kind of SD cards are they? Not all SD cards are made equally. Make sure you are buying them from reputable retailers...

Answer (score 3):

I know that when you repeatedly remove/insert an SD card it can leave "lines" on the gold contacts of the SD card itself but I haven't had any issue with it for over a year (if I'm understanding what you're saying.) Not all SD cards do this and if you're curious check this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/405942/how-much-does-it-wear-an-sd-card-to-be-frequently-removed-reinserted) out.

As for the camera messing up the card itself, do you have any other SD Card to test it? I'd recommend first getting the card, formatting it on the camera directly and taking a few test shots. Afterwards, power it off and take out out of the camera and plug it in.

Are you sure that:

- The SD card you have isn't in the **locked** position (SD cards can be "stuck" in the lock position. Tape and *cover* over the area and you should be good if that is the case.)
  [image: SD Lock Pin]
- The SD Card reader on the computer is working
- The SD Card is inserted in the correct orientation (shouldn't be a problem but worth checking)
- The SD Card isn't too old/damaged (Old cards I've found tend not to retain data as well as newer cards.)
- The Images you are viewing aren't RAWs? You may need additional software to view Nikon Raws (NEFs or related) See another [post](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/45107/how-to-open-raw-photos/45110#45110)
- The image count on the camera is decreasing with each shot.
- The images are directly **viewable** on the camera when you're previewing/looking at past images.

This isn't an exhaustive list but a good starting point. Should the card itself be the problem, its best to just buy a new card and throw the old one, probably will have more problems in the long run and cards are relatively cheap and getting cheaper nowadays.